# Правильное хранение информации о элементах

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Часто задумываюсь над этим вопросом: "Как же правильно хранить тех. информацию об элементах (например, его ID в БД)?" 
Вот есть [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xbg7ux92/1/).
Как правильно записать ID города и при нажатии на кнопку рядом с ним чтобы он показывался?
Обычно я делаю это с помощью `id="*ИД*"` или `class`, но часто говорят, что это неправильно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно хранить эту информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Атрибуты `data`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139210/) в HTML5 подошли бы. Логично их давать общему родителю всех элементов, связанных с одним городом:

```
<tr data-cityid="495">
    <td>Москва</td>
    <td><button class="btn-send">Отправить</button></td>
<tr>
```

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/xbg7ux92/3/)